# Unable to delete conditional formatting in Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have a test form with a single combo box on it, in which I set some conditional formatting based on the option selected in the box. The combo box has the tag "Conditional."

To change the conditional formatting, I have a sub called on form open. In the future, this will be applied to many combo boxes with the "Conditional" tag.

```
Private Sub ApplyCondFormatting()
    Dim objFrc As FormatCondition
    Dim ctl As Control

    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If ctl.Tag = "Conditional" Then
            With ctl
                'Remove format conditions
                .FormatConditions.Delete
                MsgBox ("Test")

                'Apply new format conditions
                Set objFrc = .FormatConditions.Add(acExpression, acEqual, "[Value] = Correct")
                Set objFrc = .FormatConditions.Add(acFieldValue, acEqual, "[Value] = Incorrect")

                'Specify the formating conditions
                .FormatConditions(0).BackColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
                .FormatConditions(0).Enabled = True
                .FormatConditions(1).BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                .FormatConditions(1).Enabled = True
            End With
        End If
    Next ctl
    Set objFrc = Nothing
End Sub
```

The MsgBox appears, so the macro *is* running properly, but it doesn't delete the old or add the new formatting. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, but it applies only "temporarily" to the currently opened form.

If you want to make it permanent, you have to open the form in **design view** beforehand

```
DoCmd.OpenForm strMyForm, acDesign
```

and save it afterwards

```
DoCmd.Save acForm, strMyForm
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without opening Design View? My code runs when the user presses a button.

Comment: @jjjjjjjjjjj: Maybe you need to further explain your situation (please edit your question to do so). If your sub runs on every Form_Open, it doesn't matter if the change is not permanent. Or does your `.FormatConditions.Delete` line not work at all, not even for the current form instance?

Comment: Hm. It should. You'll have to [debug your code](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) - add breakpoints, add a watch expression for `ctl.FormatConditions`, add a `Debug.Print ctl.FormatConditions.Count` before and after, etc.

Comment: `ctl.FormatConditions.Count` shows the correct number of FormatConditions at the correct time, yet when I right click and edit conditional formatting in design view, it's unchanged. I added details to the question. Maybe my issue lies elsewhere.

Comment: @jjjjjjjjjjj: That's exactly what I wrote in my answer. `.FormatConditions.Delete` does remove the format conditions in the currently opened instance of the form. But it has no influence on design view. This is how it's supposed to be. -- It's just like if you do `Me.ctl.BackColor = vbRed` while the form is running. It shows red, but in design view it doesn't.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks.